# How to find tables from JIRA issue description field

Tags: java, regex, jira

I have a question about how to find the begin and end of table inside a Jira issue description field.

In my case I have three possible tables inside one ticket.

```
|| Responsible | abc|
|| Departement | def |

|| SystemA Username | ghi |
|| Operation | READ |
|| Page | [Example|http://www.example.com] |

|| SystemB Username | jhk |
|| Operation | WRITE |
|| App | helloWorld |
```

Now I don't find a solution how to find all tables inside the description and how to find out which type the table is (Responsible, A, or B)

[From the JIRA API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.2.2/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html#getDescription--) will return a string (Java). I assume that regex should be the first choice.

In my first version I know only how to find the begin of the table and the end

```
^\|\| \|$
```

Is it possible to find all three tables separately? Can I get the content into a key/value collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all 3 tables in a separate match, you can use:

```
^\|\|.*\|(?:\R\|\|.*\|)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KQ8UdW/1)

You can get all 3 tables with a key value pair by for example first splitting on all empty lines.

Then you can use a pattern for every table with the `\G` anchors to get the values in 2 capture groups, that you can add to a key/value collection.

```
\G\|\|\h*(.*?)\h*\|\h*(\[[^\]\[]*\]|.*?)\h*\|\R?
```

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `\|\|\h*` Match `||` and optional spaces
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match as least as possible chars without a newline
- `\h*\|\h*` Match `|` surrounded by optional spaces
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\[[^\]\[]*\]` Match from an opening till closing square bracket
  - `|` Or
  - `.*?` atch as least as possible chars without a newline
- `)` Close group 2
- `\h*\|` Match optional spaces and `|`
- `\R?` Match an optional newline

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IuwGK3/1) and a  [Java demo](https://ideone.com/0exL8U).

For example

```
HashMap<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
String regex = "\\G\\|\\|\\h*(.*?)\\h*\\|\\h*(\\[[^\\]\\[]*\\]|.*?)\\h*\\|\\R?";
String string = "|| Responsible | abc|\n"
        + "|| Departement | def |\n\n"
        + "|| SystemA Username | ghi |\n"
        + "|| Operation | READ |\n"
        + "|| Page | [Example|http://www.example.com] |\n\n"
        + "|| SystemB Username | jhk |\n"
        + "|| Operation | WRITE |\n"
        + "|| App | helloWorld |";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);       

for (String s : string.split("(?m)^\\s*$")) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s.trim());
    while (matcher.find()) {
        m.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }
}

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " --> " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Output

```
App --> helloWorld
SystemB Username --> jhk
Departement --> def
SystemA Username --> ghi
Page --> [Example|http://www.example.com]
Operation --> WRITE
Responsible --> abc
```

Comment: I found out that's not so easy. The reality looks like this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qt8Gnl/1). There is inside the table a line break. I tried it with positive lookahead ((?=\|\n) or with (.|\n)* but I'm not able to get the line break inside the regex before the non-capturing group. Could you help me again?